# Object initialization in a method

Tags: .net

Is there a difference from POV Performance / MemoryUsage initializing a object before, or after a return condition, like in the "sample":

```
Function Foo() as ComplexObject

    ' is there a difference ??? '
    ' A '
    ' Dim obj as New ComplexObject() ' 

    If condition Then Return Nothing

    ' is there a difference ??? '        
    ' B '
    Dim obj as New ComplexObject()
    ...
    Return obj

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean, but comparison to:

```
 Dim obj as New ComplexObject()
```

*before* the `If condition Then Return Nothing`, then yes: there is a difference: it done before, then it **will** `new` an object each time, even if it is quickly discarded and collected from gen-0 (for the case when `Nothing` is returned). However, if you just *declare* it (without `New`) before the `If`, then the two should be identical (the position of the local variable is irrelevant, since all locals in IL are method-wide).

I don't know the VB, but in C# you could also use a conditional operator:

```
return condition ? null : new ComplexObject();
```

Comment: I was afraid that the compiler anyway creates(and initializes) all the declared (outside of internal cycles) objects.

Comment: A propos, the `?` in C# or `IIF` operator in VB.NET can't be used in my situation, because OR I return a Nothing(null) OR I need to do some stuff with the new ComplexObject, not just directly return it.

Comment: @serhio - the *declaration* happens at the start of the IL; however, the creation **must** happen at the same logical point as your code says it does.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that creating the object prior to returning Nothing will use an amount more CPU - either way the object will be correctly garbage collected as and when it's no longer referenced.

I'm all in favour of defining/declaring variables as late as possible.

Comment: So, you confirm that 'A' variant is more CPU and memory consuming.

Comment: I would certainly expect it to be - it's possible that the compiler would 'do the right thing' and move the object creation past the if(...) return, for an optimized release build, but I wouldn't bank on this being the case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's a difference as you are allocating a local object that once it leaves the method it needs to be garbage collected.

Comment: So, the compiler will NOT create all declared object at the beginning of the function, regardless of the declared position?

Comment: It is possible that in `Release mode the compiler detects that you are creating an object that is never used so it is possible that it removes it, but I wouldn't rely on it. Simply declare/initialize variables only when needed and as late as possible.

Comment: In fact, I think at the compile time the 'condition' can't be verified, only in Runtime this is possible.